# Weird Segmentation Fault after printing

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

Wrote a simple swap program, works well; But gives a **Segmentation Fault** after printing everything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* p1,int* p2){

    int* temp;
    *temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = *temp;
}

int main(){ 

    int a,b;
    a = 9; b = 8;
    printf("%d %d \n",a,b);
    swap(&a,&b);    
    printf("%d %d \n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9 8  
8 9  
Segmentation fault
```

Should I simply ignore this and move forward or is there something really strange going on ?

Comment: Change `int *temp` in `swap()` to `int temp`

Answer (score 2):

`int* temp;
*temp = *p1;`

is *undefined behaviour* in C and C++ as you are using an uninitialised pointer. (At the point of use, a pointer must always point to memory that you own, and your pointer isn't).

Use `int temp; temp = *p1;` instead, or better still, `int temp = *p1;`

Comment: That's the nature of *undefined behaviour*. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it eats your cat.

Comment: @Leero It's always a surprise what undefined behaviour does :D (Thats why it's called: 'undefined behaviour')

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

(`temp` is a normal `int`! Otherwise your using a uninitialized pointer which is undefined behaviour)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* p1,int* p2){

    int temp;
    temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;

}

int main(){ 

    int a = 9, b = 8;

    printf("%d %d \n",a,b);
    swap(&a, &b);    
    printf("%d %d \n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```